# Accordion tags structure - wraping tag

Tags: html, accordion

I have an accordion menu, which works fine. However, I would like to have a single wrapping tag to denote the entire accordion content.

Accordion presents a single question (in its tap) and User's response in the accordion content.

Here's what I have:

```
<div class="questions"> <!-- this div open accordion tab-->


<!-- If I place a tag here, before "QBlock" - accordion stops working -->

 <div id="QBlock"> <!-- This is where accordion content begins -->
 <table id="QTable">
   <tr>
    <td width="45" align="left" valign="top" scope="row">
      <div id="QNumber">4.2</div>
    </td>
    <td width="100%"  align="left" valign="top">
      <div id="QText">text</div>
    </td>
      </tr></table>
    </div>

 <div> 
 <table id="RTable">
   <tr>
   <td width="100%"  align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right:20px">
     <div id="Guidance"><p>content</p></div>
   </td>

   <td width="550" align="left" valign="baseline">
   <div id="Response" class="Response">
     <label><input type="radio" name="Radio402" value="Y" id="Radio_402Y" onchange='radioChange(this, "402")'>Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Radio402" value="N" id="Radio_402N" onChange='radioChange(this, "402")'>No</label>

  </div>
  <span id="responseDetails">
   <div id="Observation">
   <label for="observation">Observation:</label>
   <textarea name="observation" id="Obs402" rows="6" disabled style="width: 530px;" placeholder="Enter text of observation here ..."></textarea></div>
  <div id="DueDate">
  <label for="DueDate">Due date:<br></label>
  <input name="DueDate" type="date" id="DueDate402"/>
  </div>

  <div id="proposedActions">
  <label for="porposedActions">Proposed actions:</label>
  <textarea name="proposedActions" id="pa402" rows="6" style="width: 530px;"></textarea>
  </div>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div> <!-- this div closes the accordion tab -->
```

What I would like to do is to have a structure allowing me to wrap this whole question and place an id to it, something like

```
<section id="Q001"> ... </section>
```

which starts right ABOVE "QBlock" and ends before the final tag but accordion seems not to allow any other wrapping  . Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I cannot place a higher tag (div or section or even span) above QBlock  which would allow to wrap the entire question. If I do, accordion stops working.